# How to store weak reference object in array, dictionary in objc?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, weak-references

As we know, when you add an object to an array (NSMutableArray) or dictionary (NSMutableDictionary), it create a strong reference to the object.

Is it possible to add an object to array with a weak reference to it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1.NSValue

```
+ (NSValue *)valueWithNonretainedObject:(id)anObject
```

This method is useful if you want to add an object to a collection but don’t want the collection to create a strong reference to it.

2.There is a tricky way use block to do so:

```
typedef id (^WeakReference)(void);

WeakReference MakeWeakReference (id object) {
    __weak id weakref = object;
    return ^{ return weakref; };
}

id WeakReferenceNonretainedObjectValue (WeakReference ref) {
    if (ref == nil)
        return nil;
    else
        return ref ();
}

[arr addObject:MakeWeakReference(obj)];
id newobj = WeakReferenceNonretainedObjectValue([arr objectAtIndex:0]);
```

3.Use a custom WeakReference class that hold on a weak pointer to the value.

---

Actually, the design ideas of above methods are just the same.

Comment: better alternative: NSPointerArray

Comment: If you use valueWithNonretainedObject, then the NSValue will not contain **weak** reference but **nonretained object**. If object gets deallocated and you access to that reference, it could lead to a crash.

Comment: Tip: use `[NSPointerArray weakObjectsPointerArray]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject:` to strongly store a value that weakly references your target object.

Comment: Would other approaches such as `__weak typeof(object) weakObject = object;  [NSMutableArray addObject:weakObject];` work?  Or maybe `[NSMutableArray addObject:(id)object];`

Comment: @nhgrif I believe it won't work. NSArray create a strong reference to the object that the id-pointer point to, whatever the id-pointer is a strong pointer or a weak pointer.

Comment: @nhgrif, indeed lancy is correct, even if the variable was __weak the array would still retain the object passed.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *arrayStrong = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                      [[yourClass alloc] init],
                                      [[yourClass alloc] init], nil];

NSPointerArray *arrayWeak = [NSPointerArray weakObjectsPointerArray];

for(yourClass *obj in arrayStrong){
    [arrayWeak addPointer:(__bridge void*)(obj)];
}
```